# c++ find the first prime number

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

Find the first prime number.

The output is to find the first prime number. Something went wrong but it 
doesn't show errors. I don't know what to do, can somebody help me please.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#define MAX 100
using namespace std;

void nhap(int a[] ,int &n)
{
  do
  {
      cout<< "\nnhap so n: ";
      cin >> n;
      if(n<0 || n> MAX)
        cout << "\nsai roi, moi nhap lai ";
  }
  while(n<0 || n >MAX);

  for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
    cout << "a[" << i << "]= ";
    cin >> a[i];
  }
}

void xuat(int a[], int &n)
{
  for(int i=0; i <n; i++)
    cout << a[i] << " ";
}

int nguyentodt(int a[], int &n)
{
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
    int d=0;
    for(int s=0; s<=a[i]; s++ )
    {
      if( a[i]% s ==0)
        d++;
    }
    if(d==2)
      return a[i];
  }
  return -1;
}

int main()
{
  int n;
  int a[MAX];
  nhap(a,n);
  xuat(a,n);
  cout << " \nso nguyen to dau tien la: ";
  cout << nguyentodt(a,n);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code to see where it goes wrong compared to what you thought it should do?

Comment: you type in n and a[i], and it will print out the first prime number
for example
n=3
a[1]=1
a[2]=2
a[3]=3
it suppose to print out the first prime number which is 2

Comment: _"Something went wrong"_ What does it mean? Please, provide details.

Comment: it doesn't print the first prime number

Answer (score 1):

Bellow condition checks in a loop which starts from `0`:

```
if (a[i] % s == 0)
```

As I said `s` starts from `0`, so in first step you have division by zero exception. you need to start your loop from `1`;